# Как проредить подписи в chartview?

Tags: qml

Если в бар серии много "столбиков" то текст под ними не всего умещается. Кто как с этим борется?

Comment: Те подписи, которые не умещаются превращаются в точки (...)

Comment: Выводить подписи не для каждого бара, а с каким-то шагом: через 2, 3, 5, 100. А для того, чтобы решить с каким именно шагом - высчитывать расстояние между барами и сравнивать его с шириной какого-либо типичного текста-подписи.

Comment: вооот.... а как это сделать :)

Comment: Посмотрел на этот QtChart поближе, кхм... короче, никак. Очень он деревянный )

Comment: Смотри) Можно взять категории(они стринглист) потом узнать их метрики с помощью ТекстМетрик, путем математических вычислений попробовать отпределить влезают или не влезают. Ах да.. забыл. Еще наложить поверх мнимую шкалу на бар (эту шкалу урезать, а основную скрыть с помощью визибл) Расстояние между барами вычислить не получится, но вот ширину разделить на количество столбиков мы узнаем среднедопустимую ширину

Comment: Если решение задачи доходит, то абсурда, то надо поменять условие задачи ) Так вот, в таких случаях, я просто меняю структуру интерфейса, а в данном конкретном случае можно, наверное, поместить график в ScrollArea. А то как в старом советском анекдоте про удаление гланд через жепу